# Sort array of numbers using tree sort - Leetcode 912

Tags: sorting, time-limit-exceeded, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

[Problem statement](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-an-array/description):
Sort integer array `nums` in O(N log N) time,
without relying on any library sort routine.

I am trying to use a tree sort method (using the creation of a BST and then performing inorder traversal) in order to sort an array of numbers. I have the following code:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution:
    def sortArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:

        output = []

        def insert(node, val):
            if not node:
                return TreeNode(val)
            
            if val <= node.val:
                node.left = insert(node.left, val)
            else:
                node.right = insert(node.right, val)
            
            return node

        root = TreeNode(nums[0])
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            root = insert(root, nums[i])
        
        def inorder(root):
            if not root:
                return
            
            inorder(root.left)
            output.append(root.val)
            inorder(root.right)
        
        inorder(root)

        return output
```

I am getting a TLE (time limit exceeded) error. I am not sure if there is an optimization to do in order to tighten up time from recursive stack calls in both the `insert()` function. I am not sure if the recursive solution is not optimal (given the amount of recursive calls used). Perhaps I need to approach with an iterative approach in order to build the BST during the `insert()` calls?

Comment: Merge sort has worst case O(nlogn) time complexity, and in my opinion is easier to code than self balancing trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## edge case

I feel the first result displayed here is reasonable:

```
>>> sorted([])
[]
>>> sorted([6, 4])
[4, 6]
```

Given zero elements, and asked to spit them back in ascending order,
the proper response is zero elements.

In contrast, your `TreeNode(nums[0])` call
catastrophically raises IndexError in the empty case.

## base case

Your `insert` function is lovely.

```
        root = TreeNode(nums[0])
```

Caller might possibly have preferred to DRY this up with

```
        root = insert(None, nums[0])
```

so that only `insert` needs to worry about that detail.

## globals

```
        def inorder(root):
```

See, now this is where "nested `def`s" gets a bad name.
Your `insert` was beautiful.
It could have been a separate (testable!) `@staticmethod`,
but it's simple and it fit in nicely.

In contrast, this function should probably have a signature of

```
        def inorder(output, root):
```

(Plus, `output` was perhaps initialized a bit early,
so we have nearly forgotten about it by the time it is used.)

Ok, enough about
[coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).

## time complexity

When you approach a cryptography problem,
or an OWASP cyber security problem,
or even a simple sort,
you have to have a mind-set that
the whole world is out to get you.
The computer, the internet, and especially the adversary.
Which in this case would be the LeetCode folks.

Now, imagine a happy world, with unicorns prancing
beneath rainbows. You get N integers to sort.
And guess what?
It's a random permutation of natural numbers up to N.
Life is good, your Binary Tree algorithm can blaze
through them, inserting each number in O(log N) time.

But then the next day storm clouds have come out,
the shy unicorns have run away,
and LeetCode sends you one of these as input:

- `list(range(n))`
- `list(reversed(range(n)))`

Will `insert` run in logarithmic time?
Heavy sigh!
It needs O(N) linear time to chase through
those unbalanced nodes.
Total sort time is O(N²) quadratic.
We are ruined!

Fortunately this is an off-line (batch) sort --
you are given the numbers all at once.
It's not like we're trying to maintain an online
[pqueue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)
or anything.
If you want to save the current algorithm,
you could **enforce** the randomness requirement with
[Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)
pre-conditioning at linear cost.
Not that I've ever seen anyone do that in real production code.
Plus, it would behave suboptimally if given N `0`'s
plus a single `1` to sort.

Consider looking into one of the various
[Balanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)
binary tree datastructures, such as a
[heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)
or the ever popular
[red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did run into issues with reversed/already-sorted ranges so I implemented Fisher-Yates to randomize (of course this wouldn't be good programming practice in real-life).

However, I noticed for a long list of duplicate values (i.e., `[2] * n`) Fisher-Yates and a classic BST construction scheme fails. I will try a red-black tree approach and then implement a heap approach in another run.

Comment: Sooo, when there's **many** duplicates, this approach will tend to have trouble. Of course, so many duplicates implies we can just [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), and determining that requires just O(n) linear time to construct a histogram. We are willing to allocate a "small" histogram, much smaller than N, and we bail with fatal error if it turns out to be "large". A limiting case would be [3] + [2]*n. The histogram tells us that only `2` and `3` are present. We output `n` copies of `2` followed by 1 copy of `3` and we're done. // Or keep a count in each tree node.